# How to write JS function in a .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a function in Html and it works well. [image]
But My teacher said we need separate the code out of HTML file. So I need to implement this code in a .js file. Can anyone tell me how to do that? I think to create a function in JS like this but it not working.[image]

Thanks for any help!

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#down").on('click',function(event) {
$('html,div-b').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight 
-1100},"slow");

 });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to create a function, just move all your code into this file.

Comment: @Walk is right, just move the code to the separate JS file and then link to that JS file in the HTML file.

Comment: Please add your code as text in your psot, it's easier to work with than images

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for your help. But actually, There already have some function my teammate wrote in the JS file. I tried to copy the code to top of all javascript, but it can't work

Comment: @Wndrr oh, I forgot it. Thanks, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use **html** file like this

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="demo.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and keep the **js** file like this
**demo.js** file

```
function test(){
<!---your code here-->
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. We already have a js file called 'myJS' and linked with the HTML. We also have some different function in 'myJS' file. I tried to create a test function with the code but it seems can't work

Comment: Check whether both html and js are in same path,if js is in different path mention the correct path

Comment: yeah, the path is right. and all other function works well. only the scroll down function I just wrote can't work.

Comment: check whether it is throwing any error in console?? put an alert and check whether the alert is firing

Comment: Yeah, I think my teammate found how to fix it. thanks for the help again!

Comment: That's fine keep coding :)

Comment: For future readers, if you have the code in a script tag and when you move the code to a file you add it inside a function, you should call that function somewhere so its code is executed. For example, if you use jQuery you could have a `$(function(){ myFunction(); });` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

copy the code inside the <'script> tag and paste in a separate .js file . This is how it works

Comment: Thanks for your help. We already have a js file called 'myJS' and linked with the HTML. We also have some different function in 'myJS' file. I tried to create a test function with the code but it seems can't work

Answer (score 1):

Put all the js code in a .js file, then put the code below in the html page which will call it, inside the head or the body.

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. We already have a js file called 'myJS' and linked with the HTML. We also have some different function in 'myJS' file. I tried to create a test function with the code but it seems can't work

Comment: A function should be called, or in the js file itself, or with some other js code, something like jsfunction()

Answer (score 1):

Write the code as it is in file and save it with .js extension and link it in html under head tag as follows

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. We already have a js file called 'myJS' and linked with the HTML. We also have some different function in 'myJS' file. I tried to create a test function with the code but it seems can't work

Comment: If you create a function as we create in javascript(ex. function scrolldown(){}) , then you have to call them from html. otherwise it wont work because javascript does not use selection framework which jquery use.So dont write your code in scrolldown function.